# The log file is not shrinking with SQL Shrink

Tags: sql, sql-server, shrink

I'm trying to perform a shrink operation on SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), but the log file is not shrinking. Is there a specific code that can be used in this situation? Can you help me with the code for this?

I attempted to shrink the LOG file but was unable to do so.

Comment: Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/shrink-a-file?view=sql-server-ver16 for possible reasons.

Comment: Most likely the recovery model of your database is FULL, and you're not doing transaction log backups. You can't simply "delete" the information in that log file, it is being retained for a reason. Too much to go into in the comment section.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does `SELECT name, log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases;` return?

Answer (score -1):

When you shrink Database, Only the mdf File Shrinks.
and the ldf File (Which is LOG file) will have no changes.

If you want to reduce the size of ldf File, right click on Database, on properties>Files set the Size(Mb) of your LOG file. after setting that(if db recovery is simple) it reduces.
Also you can Limit Max size of LOG file in properties>Files Autogrouth/MaxSize settings.